# Trouble in managing session (HTTP Session) in struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, websphere, session-state, httpsession

we are getting a huge trouble in managing session in our web application. When a huge number of user accessing the application, there is some scenario where multiple users trying to perform the same action at the same moment(even in nanoseconds).

We have page tracker and session tracker for each user which are unique. And in each and every page the values of those trackers should match for a single user to proceed.

But while a huge number of the user is accessing our application we are getting few scenarios where the value of these two trackers is not matching surprisingly. My expected reason is that there are multiple users who are trying to perform the same operation at the very same moment. we are using struts 2. Kindly help us with your expert solutions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Why does it matter if multiple users are trying to do the same thing? What's a "page tracker"? What's the issue?

Comment: I would guess that you might have some non-thread-safe variables/attributes somewhere in your application.

Comment: Hi Dave and Dbreaux, Page tracker is a variable, value of which is set with session key once a user logs into application whereas Session tracker is another variable which has the same value of page tracker but maintained across the pages for a single user. So, a user will be allowed to proceed with next operation ONLY when the page tracker value and session tracker value matches in every single page user wants to operate.

Comment: Hi Dbreaux, We have loadpagedata() method in Action class which helps us to load content(Or you can say initialisation). Inside this method, "PageTracker" and "SessionTracker" are local variables.